# How to move magento 2 my account page title section after page top

Tags: magento2

How to move magento 2 my account page title section below page top in full width as shown below 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/Theme/theme-name/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="page.top" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```